# How quickly is the desired state of curl of the Electric Field around a point achieved where a Magnetic Field Vector has just begun changing?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, maxwell-equations, causality

*My question and context with explanation are given below. Thank you in advance.*

**Faraday’s Law () states that a time-changing magnetic field vector induces a curl of the Electric field around that point.** However it does not specify how quickly the necessary spatial gradient is developed in the Electric Field to satisfy that curl. Of course, the Electric Field vectors around that point cannot just jump to the required values instantaneously in accompaniment as soon as the magnetic field starts changing at a fixed rate, since it is required that the Electric Field has a sensible rate of change to in turn induce a curl of the magnetic Field and continue the propagation of the wave. It would seem the exact rates at which the Electric and Magnetic Fields are changing is critical in the mechanism of an EM wave’s propagation. **How would I then calculate the rate of change of E somewhere along the wave given I know the rate of change of the B vector that began it, and given the wave is restricted to one dimension for simplicity?** There should after all be some delay in how the EM wave moves from point to point in space, seeing as it moves at the finite speed of causality (3*10^8 m/s), as shown in the first image:

[image: maths]

Some of my ideas so far have been that perhaps the rate of change of E is determined such that it exactly cancels the growth of the time-changing E vector that gave rise to a curl of B before, which developed at such a rate to induce a curl of E, which demands this rate of change of E which I am talking about now. In this way the wave might level out the growth of the fields in its wake and spread the change further outwards, in the same way smoothening out a crease spreads it elsewhere. However I am stuck on how to show this rigorously.

I am open to any difficulty of maths, so long as the answer provides the explanation. Below are some diagrams to help visualize what I am talking about:

[image: images]

*Faraday's Law requires that a curl of E is developed, which under these restrictions requires a spatial gradient of E to appear across that point. Since the field across that point was previously in some other state, it is required that the Electric Field vectors that are infinitesimally close to that point undergo a rate of change through time to achieve the desired state of curl. The question is, how quickly is this desired state of curl achieved?*

Comment: Please enter your text as text so that we can copy and paste it when answering your question and so future readers will be able to find your question by text search.

Answer (score 0):

You are under the misapprehension that a change in B-field "causes" a curling E-field. The two things are part of the electromagnetic field and co-exist. Nothing about Faraday's law tells you that one causes the other. The rate of change of B-field and (minus) the curl of E-field are equal at every point in space and time.

Comment: So if the B-field suddenly starts increasing at a steady rate (say the current giving rise to it is undergoing uniform acceleration) , the E-field around a point where B is changing will instantaneously change, with no sensible rate of change, from the existing state of curl to a curl in accordance with the new time-changing B-field, such that Faradays Law is satisfied at every point in space and time?

Comment: This does not seem logical to me - that a field can just change its value instantaneously - and furthermore if there is no delay in how the state of curl is achieved to satisfy Faradays Law, how can there exist a sensible rate of change of the E-field according to which a curl of B must then exist, which as we know must exist to continue the propagation of an EM wave. Thanks

Comment: "So if the B-field suddenly starts increasing at a steady rate" is a synonymous phrase of "if the curl of the electric field suddenly has a constant value".  Further: "the E-field around a point where B is changing" - I cannot comment. What matters is *the point* where the B-field changes. Of course there is a delay in a change in one place influencing the fields at another place. The statement in my answer is absolutely factual.

Comment: I agree with your statement "The rate of change of B-field and (minus) the curl of E-field are equal at every point in space and time" -as you say, the 2 coexist, you cannot have one without the other.

Comment: So at the very instant the B-field at a point suddenly starts increasing at a steady rate, the gradients of the Electric Field at that 'point' (and hence the Electric Field vectors which are infinitesimally close to that point) will instantaneously adjust themselves to instantaneously achieve the new state of curl.

Comment: As you say, "Of course there is a delay in a change in one place influencing the fields at another place", so how could you agree with the notion that changes in the B-field at one point affect the state of the E-field which is infinitesimally close to, though still at a distance from that point, with no delay at all? If you know the definition of the curl, it is based on the limit of the circulation-enclosed area ratio of a field around a point as the closed path shrinks onto the point in question, albeit always remains some distance away from it, however miniscule.

Comment: The curl considers the infinitesimal neighbourhood of the point, not just 'the point.'

Comment: My question remains Professor Jeffries, although it's fine if you don't wish to answer it. Regardless, thank you for your time.